# Body of request is empty when reading as a [FromBody]

Tags: c#

Here is my server function assignment :

```
[HttpPost("RestaurantWorkingHours")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddRestaurantWorkingHours([FromBody] HoursMultipleDays HoursMultipleDay){
context.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
    string body;
    using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body))
    {
        body = await stream.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
// body is empty
}
```

anyway the content is empty

here how i send in postman

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7F7i.png]

Comment: Try to post data using Postman or different API tool. Then pass a screen here so we can ensure data is sent corectly

Comment: Which version of .Net are you using?

Comment: @TomasChabada  4.8

Comment: Does the JSON satisfy the structure of the `HoursMultipleDays` class?

Comment: @FrankAlvaro Yes! The HoursMultipleDays consist of an object RestaurantWorkingHous and an integer list Days

Comment: Have you tried to remove the [FromBody]? In some versions it was unnecessary

Comment: Yes I did , There was no effect for my purpose . @TomasChabada

Answer (score 0):

I am confused. Why are you adding an extra ActionExecutingContext reader to the pipeline?
If you expand your method `AddRestaurantWorkingHours` like this

```
[HttpPost("RestaurantWorkingHours")]
public HttpResponseMessage AddRestaurantWorkingHours([FromBody] HoursMultipleDays HoursMultipleDay)
{
  var x = 0; // set breakpoint here
}
```

You should see data in your `HoursMultipleDay` object. There is no need to read / parse / misuse the context object for this.

Comment: I did it only to make it clear to understand , i use it in the main function which accepts ActionExecutingContext